# Auto Sign-In to Power BI through code so as the report is visible in 'Secure Embed Code'

Tags: iframe, powerbi, embed, secure-coding

**Issue:**

On several ios devices, after clicking on 'Sign-In' button within the iframe(having src as Power BI report 'Secure Embed Code'), a new window opens to sign in to Power BI and after successful sign in, the window closes. **However, iframe does not get reloaded. A manual intervention to reload the page is required to view the report. This exists on several ios devices (irrespective of the browser chrome or safari).**

**Implementation:**

We have a web application using Azure AD Authentication, in this web application, we are embedding the Power BI reports with the help of 'Secure Embed Code' in an iframe.

**Current Workflow:**

1) User sign in to the web application ->

2) Iframe (having secure embed code) is displayed with a ***Sign-In*** button ->

3) User clicks on **'Sign-In'** button within the iframe ->

4) A new window opens for few seconds to log in to Power BI Services ->

5) This new window closes automatically after successful login to Power BI Service ->

6) Iframe reloads and report is displayed

This flow works fine for Windows and Android devices. However, for several ios devices, Step#6(Iframe reload) does not work.

I am aware of the limitation of 'Secure Embed code' as

> Some browsers require you to refresh the page after sign-in, especially when using InPrivate or InCognito modes.

Refer Limitations section of [link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/) for details.

**Required Functionality:**

After sign-in to the application, before rendering of any iframe, a link should be provided which generates a new window and prompt user to sign in into the Power BI Services. After successful SignIn in the new window, a message should be passed to the previous window that 'signIn is successful' and the new window should be closed. Once our application receives this message 'signIn is successful', then the iframe should be rendered. This will help us resolve the issue that exists in ios devices.

**Note: We do not want to use 'App Owns Data/User Owns Data' approach as these approaches require to purchase dedicated capacity for production.**

***Please suggest if this is possible and provide some reference as to how could we achieve this. 
Or suggest if there is any other workaround to resolve the issue.***

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: We do not want to use 'App Owns Data/User Owns Data' approach as these approaches require to purchase dedicated capacity for production.

No, this isn't true. You will need dedicated capacities if you use embed tokens (e.g. generated with [GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup)). You can embed reports with [AAD tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token) and keep using shared capacities (see [tokenType](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) property).

The inconvenience that you are trying to overcome comes from the way secure embedding is implemented. This is how this feature works. Microsoft didn't made it because they wanted to make it inconvenient for the users. They made it this way, because it wasn't possible or easy enough to implement it better. You have to either way for a while, until browsers changes or Microsoft updates this feature, or use proper embedding (user owns data scenario in your case).

Comment: Just for clarification, This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization#using-a-power-bi-premium-dedicated-capacity) describes the implementation of the same approach i.e. _User Owns Data_. 

However, at the end of the document, its mentioned that **we should purchase dedicated capacity to back up our workspaces**. 
Is dedicated capacity mandatory for the production environment? Is there any limit for access tokens as it is for embed tokens or access tokens are unlimited for Power BI Pro licensed user.

Comment: It is not written that you **should** buy a dedicated capacity. *By creating a dedicated capacity, you can take advantage of having a dedicated resource for the content in your app workspace.* So it will give you the advantage of having a dedicated hardware for your reports, so you can rely on it all the time and don't worry about "noisy neighbors", etc. AAD tokens are not limited. They are used for other authentication too. However usually they have more privileges than needed and keep in mind that they are visible in client's JavaScript code and can be hijacked and used for other API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Andrey. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this "No, this isn't true. You will need dedicated capacities if you use embed tokens (e.g. generated with GenerateTokenInGroup). You can embed reports with AAD tokens and keep using shared capacities" apply to  "App Owns Data" approach as well?  @AndreyNikolov

Comment: It is not directly related to the scenario. AAD tokens are generated from ADAL/MSAL and are not limited. Embed tokens are generated from Power BI REST API (GenerateTokenInGroup) and if there is no dedicated capacity assigned to this workspace (i.e. Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded), you have a limited number of tokens, that you can generate. This is enough for development, but when when you go to production, this number of tokens will be quickly exceeded and your app will stop working. That's why you need to buy Premium, or use AAD tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response  Andrey !

Comment: @Sakshi Gupta, How did you achieve it? Could you please explain in brief? I also have the same requirement.